# Integral of $\ln f(x)$

Tags: integration, derivatives, logarithms, taylor-expansion, approximation

I know that
$\displaystyle\int\ln(f(x))dx=x\ln(f(x))-\int\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}dx$ which seemingly cannot be further compacted (i.e. it requires to know $f$). In my problem $f$ is (pretty well form) as follows:

$$f(x)=c+d(1-\frac{\cosh\frac{x}{a}}{\cosh\frac{b}{2a}})$$

for $\displaystyle-\frac{b}{2}<x<\frac{b}{2}$. I'm struggling to obtain a compact solution for $$\int_{-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{b}{2}}\ln(f(x))dx$$

In fact, the second term ($\displaystyle\int_{-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{b}{2}}\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}dx$) ends up being so ugly. Any effort on finding a compact form would be highly appreciated.

---

PS While one may use Euler’s representation or Taylor expansion, it is more desirable to have the final answer in a compact hyperbolic form. Any clever idea for **approximating** the integral is also very welcome (rough ranges: $c=350, d=5, b=1e-4, a=4e-6$). I'm not sure if it helps but FYI: $f$ is obtained by solving $f''-\frac{(f-c)}{a^2}=-\frac{d}{a^2}$ and compacting the solution nicely.

Comment: A general advice on how to hack $\int \ln(f(x))dx$ or $\int \frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}dx$ could be helpful.

Comment: I suppose that the antiderivative would express in terms of polylogarithms.

Comment: As I wrote in a previous comment, there is a closed form expression for tha antiderivative. The problem is that it is a **monster**  involving  polylogarithm functions $\text{Li}_2(z)$ where the argument $z$ is another one.

Comment: In Mathematica with your data for constants $a,b,c,d$ I got $28.60518414920374$ but the general result is ugly

Comment: Unclear what you call a *compact* solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Taylor expansion

$$\log f(x)\approx \log \left(c+d- \frac{d}{\cosh \left(\frac{a b}{2}\right)}\right)-\frac{d x^2}{2 a^2 \left((c+d) \cosh \left(\frac{a b}{2}\right)-d\right)}$$

Plugging your data I got the value of the integral $I=28.605$ the error is less than $10^{-3}$ because your $\frac{b}{2}$ is about $2.4$

If you need more precision there is the $4$th degree term which is much uglier than the second one LOL and gives one more exact decimal

$$\log f(x)\approx -\frac{d x^4 \left((c+d) \cosh \left(\frac{a b}{2}\right)+2 d\right)}{24 a^4 \left(d-(c+d) \cosh \left(\frac{a b}{2}\right)\right)^2}-\frac{d x^2}{\cosh \left(\frac{a b}{2}\right) \left(2 a^2 \left(-\frac{d}{\cosh \left(\frac{a b}{2}\right)}+c+d\right)\right)}+\\ \log \left(-\frac{d}{\cosh \left(\frac{a b}{2}\right)}+c+d\right)$$

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Are you using Taylor expansion at $b/2a$? If so, its value is 12.5. Here, it is important to come up with a compact and nice form, the value or computation is not tough. How does your final solution look like?

Comment: No,no I expanded at $x=0$ and the best you can get is the first formula, the one with second degree $x$. $Mathematica gave me the exact formula, but is ten lines long full of polylog and other stuff

Comment: It's not clear for me how you obtained your talyor series of log(x), I tired but could not get what you got. Can you please show

Comment: @JohnButler Used $Mathematica$ :)

Answer (score 2):

Your integrand can be written, after rescaling the variable and renaming/pulling out the constants,

$$\log(e^x+e^{-x}+h),$$ or

$$\log(e^{2x}+he^x+1)-x.$$

If we assume the roots of the trinomial to be real, we can finally reduce to terms of the form

$$\log(e^z+1)$$ for which the antiderivative can be expressed as

$$-\text{Li}_2(-e^{z})$$ where $\text{Li}_2$ is known as the *dilogarithm* function, a particular case of the *polylogarithm*. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function)

The result still holds for complex roots, with more difficult computation.

Answer (score 0):

The complete answer can be found [in the last chapter of my Ph.D. dissertation][1] in detail:

```
https://escholarship.org/content/qt9t34j0zw/qt9t34j0zw.pdf
```